# How to select table Dynamically on Mysql store procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Hey i was trying to  write a code to check the record existence  from many tables, 
Is there any way to give table names dynamically?

what i am upto see below code

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `_relatives` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `_relatives`(
  IN db_database VARCHAR(55),
  IN db_table VARCHAR(55),
  IN db_column_no VARCHAR(55),
  IN _id INT(15),
  OUT last_inserted_id INT(15)
)
BEGIN

 IF ( SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CONCAT(' ', db_table, ' ') WHERE CONCAT('`', db_column_no, '`')= CONCAT(' ', _id, ' ') ) )
 THEN 
            SELECT 'data';
ELSE
            SELECT 'No data';
   END IF; 

   SET last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

END $$
```

DELIMITER ;

i code is not working .. please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need use [13.5. SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).